# Is my question really too broad or is it something else?

Tags: discussion

I asked a question about the proportion of BAs vs BSs awarded in anthropology and linguistics ([Do more people earn BAs or BSs in Linguistics?](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/105484/do-more-people-earn-bas-or-bss-in-linguistics)). It was almost instantly put on hold by several people with the explanation that it was too broad. I immediately restricted it to linguistics only and in the US, and yet several days have passed without any change.

I'm perplexed to start with that this was considered too broad, because there are absolutely far broader and vaguer questions up at pretty much all times that end up with many upvotes, so I'm starting to think that it's not actually too broad and that the real problem is something else, perhaps that it's considered a "polling question"? If that's the case, what is the appropriate way to ask a question that can be answered with demographic data?

Comment: I don't think so. If it asked about math someone would pull the AMS data and be done. I think it is a somewhat boring, but perfectly reasonable and answerable question.

Comment: I think that with the added country tag it's a reasonable question, and I voted to reopen. At the moment there are 4 reopen votes, so there are chances that it gets reopened.